# Football match prediction using regression

Tags: neural-network, keras, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I am trying to predict goal difference of football matches in keras using a single layer Neural Network. I used mse as metrics and its a low value aroung 0.05 but some predictions has huge difference.
[image: goal Difference Prediction vs Goal Difference Test]

I tried sklearn LinearRegression too but results were almost same. Also I have tried multiple layers network too but results were almost same too.

Any ideas to lower the predicted difference?

Answer (score 1):

If your MSE is low, but then your predictions on the test set are way off, i can think only of over-fitting either you're leaking information from the training set to the test set ( or vice-versa ) or you simply have a complex model ( too many features ) which you could solve by increasing your data or going for less features.

That's a first diagnosis, maybe you could plot your learning curves so you can check your variance/bias and tell which one of those problems you have.

Comment: Okay.btw my r2 score is 0.62. whats your thoughts about this?